# Тэги в Objective-C

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Не судите строго, вопрос новичка по тэгам в obj-c.
У меня есть три UITextField которым я задал тэги [textField setTag:1] и т.д.

Я хочу перемещаться между ними посредством изменения проперти firstResponder. То есть моя задача выглядит так:

```
-(IBAction) nextTextFieldBecomeFirstResponder: 
if ([[textfield.tag ==1] isFirstresponder])  {
      [[textField.tag == 2] becomeFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Но конечно выражение [textfield.tag ==1] не работает. Вопрос: как правильно записать обращение к конкретному объекту по его тэгу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно не помню как такое реализовывал, но первое что приходит в голову это записать textField'ы в массив, а затем в методе обработчике делать вот так

```
-(IBAction) nextTextFieldBecomeFirstResponder:(UITextField *)currentTextField {
    UITextField *nextTextField = [self.textFields objectAtIndex:currentTextField.tag + 1];
    [nextTextFielf becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

З.Ы. ну и проверяйте tag на выход за пределы массива.

Comment: Интересное решение, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

1. если Ваши UITextField лежат, к примеру, в self.view, их можно найти через 
   [self.view viewWithTag: 1].
2. можете отказаться от тегов в пользу трех именованных IBOutlet
3. можете отказаться от тегов в пользу IBOutletCollection

Comment: Дело в том что textField'ы описаны как property в кастомных сеll'ах  и прямого доступа из view к ним нет. Можете описать синтаксис обращения к  textField'у в таком случае?